# How to call Service from activity without interrupting the activity?

Tags: android, android-service

I created a Simple Activity which contains a button. On clicking the button, a Toast message should appear. Also, I wrote a Service, which should be called when the app launches. So, I used the following code,

`startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));`

in the OnCreate() method. When the app launches, the service gets called, and it's working, but not the current activity. I understand that the using of intent navigates the app to the service. I couldn't figure out how to make both things work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your service is running in a different thread, the activity would not be interrupted, which depends on what kind of service you have used. Which class does your service class extends ?

Comment: My class extends Service class. And I have tried calling the service from a separate thread as well. If the thread works, the activity is not working. The UI is just stuck

Comment: You dont have to call the service from a seperate thread, you have to make the service run in a separate thread, as in the service should create a thread to perform its operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was to not run the service in a separate thread. I corrected it :) Thanks for the help !

Answer (score -1):

It is available to start a service from your main activity's onCreate(Bundle) method. In your case the main activity should be the SimpleActivity. I just created a test project, both Activity and Service works fine. Have you registered your Activity in AndroidManifest.xml, and have you called super.onCreate and setContentView in your Activity's onCreate method?

Comment: When I call a service from main activity, the service is getting executed, but not the button in the UI.

Comment: I think it's not caused by starting the service. To prove if it is or not, just comment or delete the line startService(...) and run again. If the button is still not there, then the problem is not caused by starting a service.

Comment: I dont think that the  issue is about buttons visibility, its about its click, which is not working which is because the service running on the ui thread

Comment: I just read your reply to Ashish and now I guess your service is doing time-consuming jobs like "while(xxx){xxxxx}". If this is the case, you should start a new Thread in the Service to do time-consuming things.